# Smoothly object transition through lerp and coroutine

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
IEnumerator SmoothlyShiftPosition(Vector3 destination, float OverTime) {

    float startTime = 0;
    while (startTime < OverTime)
    {
        Debug.Log(startTime/OverTime + "changing: " + navigationCanvas.transform.position);
        Debug.Log("startTime : " + startTime);
        navigationCanvas.transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(navigationCanvas.transform.position, destination, startTime/OverTime);
        startTime += Time.deltaTime * 2f;
        yield return null;
    }
    navigationCanvas.transform.position = destination;
}
```

I have this simple code snippet which i am using to lerp my object to specfied position smoothly it work sometime correctly but  not always. I logged different data and **found that my startTime variable sometime *becomes zero* continuously**. I am unable to figure why this occuring? what i am doing wrong

I am calling my coroutine like this

```
if (SmoothlyShiftPositionIEum != null) {
                            StopCoroutine(SmoothlyShiftPositionIEum);
                        }
                       SmoothlyShiftPositionIEum = StartCoroutine(SmoothlyShiftPosition(navCanvas, smoothPositionTime));
```

Comment: @Programmer you should need to understand question first

Comment: Can you show the code that starts the coroutine?

Comment: @LeoBartkus i have updated my question

Comment: Are  you sure you aren't stopping and re-starting the coroutine every update()?

Comment: @LeoBartkus at some condition this thing is happening

Comment: Yea, what condition calls the coroutine?   If your coroutine calling code happens every update, it will stop the coroutine every update.   This will reset the startTime to 0 over and over.  Because startTime exists inside the coroutine's scope, a new startTime variable is created and initialized each time you restart it.